# django custom manager manytomany field add

Tags: django

My code for custom manager below:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        obj, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='group1')
        kwargs.update({'groups': obj})
        return super(CustomManager, self).create(**kwargs)
```

which creates `TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is specified, you can not directly pass a `groups=` in a create. You can use [**`.set(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) (or [**`.add(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)) for example, so:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        object = super(CustomManager, self).create(**kwargs)
        group, __ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='group1')
        object.groups.set([group])
        return object
```

Comment: getting `TypeError: 'Group' object is not iterable`

Comment: @nikolas: sorry that should be a list (or tuple), somehow the `.add` and the `.set` have different signatures.